# How to load EF tools from another folder into package manager console?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

We're creating a global architecture for all products of our company, and we've come to have a very specific file-system structure in which `packages` folder should not be in the root of solutions directory.

Of course we can reference EF dll files from somewhere else, because it's configuration is done in `csproj` file.

However, when we delete packages folder, `add-migration` breaks, because it depends on the tools existing in the `tools` folder.

Is it possible to add paths to Nuget package management console? or is it possible to use add-migrations out of *PMC*, or do we have any other choice?

Based on our experience we think it should be possible, but we can't find out how.